# Different results with caret when classProbs=TRUE

Tags: r, r-caret

When I train to models, one using classProbs=TRUE and the other without computing the probabilities, I get different results:

```
library(caret)

set.seed(7)
myControl <- trainControl(method='cv',number=3,savePredictions=TRUE)
set.seed(7)
model <- train(Species~., iris, tuneLength=4,method='svmRadial', trControl=myControl)

set.seed(7)
myControl <- trainControl(method='cv',number=3,savePredictions=TRUE,classProbs=TRUE)
set.seed(7)
modelProbs <- train(Species~., iris, tuneLength=4, method='svmRadial', trControl=myControl)
```

The model with classProbs=FALSE (var model) is:

```
C     Accuracy   Kappa      Accuracy SD  Kappa SD  
0.25  0.9266667  0.8900100  0.03055050   0.04584410
0.50  0.9333333  0.8999840  0.02309401   0.03469643
1.00  0.9400000  0.9099880  0.02000000   0.03004800
2.00  0.9400000  0.9100059  0.02000000   0.02999416
```

And the model with classProbs=TRUE (var modelProb) is:

```
C     Accuracy   Kappa     Accuracy SD  Kappa SD  
0.25  0.9266667  0.890010  0.03055050   0.04584410
0.50  0.9333333  0.899984  0.02309401   0.03469643
1.00  0.9400000  0.909988  0.02000000   0.03004800
2.00  0.9466667  0.919980  0.02309401   0.03466529
```

resulting even in different final models after parameter selection (C=1 when classProbs=FALSE and C=2 when classProbs=TRUE).

I have found out that all predictions are equal for both models except those where the classifier is not very sure of which class to predict. For example:

```
> model$pred[423,]
          pred        obs rowIndex     sigma    C Resample
423 versicolor versicolor       69 0.8071298 0.25    Fold3

> modelProbs$pred[423,]
         pred        obs     setosa versicolor virginica rowIndex        sigma    C Resample
423 virginica versicolor 0.03307154  0.4813102 0.4856182       69 0.8071298 0.25    Fold3
```

In this experiment, differences are very small but I have tried with more complex data, and differences are huge. Can anybody explain how the classProbs attribute affects to predictions? I thought it was used to view the probabilities for each class but that it didn't change the results.

Comment: In your post, results are the same. Please revise.

Comment: Actually it is done by the kernlab package and the package documents explains as 'In classification when prob.model is TRUE a 3-fold cross validation is performed on the data and
a sigmoid function is fitted on the resulting decision values f.'. I guess it'd be the source of discrepancy - page 57 http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kernlab/kernlab.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your response @JaehyeonKim. Doing more research I have found this post that answers my question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503027/why-are-probabilities-and-response-in-ksvm-in-r-not-consistent]. The problem is that in my real experiment, which has 121 classes, using the model without probs I get 50% accuracy with a standard 10 folds cv, but when the probs are computed, it drops down to less than 15%!